# Select TOP N not working in MS Access with parameter

Tags: ms-access

In SQL Server, we use this sQL for `set rowcount`:

```
SET ROWCOUNT @top
```

or

```
select top (@top) * from Table
```

How to use this query in MS Access SQL?

Answer (score 3):

Access does not support using a parameter for `SELECT TOP`.  You must write a literal value into the text of the SQL statement.