# Access SubQuery: SHOW TOP (count form select query) Table

Tags: database, ms-access

Is it possible to use a Count() or number from another Select query to SELECT TOP a number of rows in a different query?

Below is a sample of the update query I'm trying to use but would like to take the count from another query to replace "10".

```
...
WHERE Frames.Package IN (
   SELECT TOP 10 Frames
   FROM Frames.Package WHERE Package = "100" 
   ORDER BY Frames.ReferenceNumber
)
```

So for example, i've tried to do

```
SELECT TOP SelectQuery.RecordCount Frames
```

Sample SelectQuery.RecordCount

```
SELECT COUNT(Frames.Package) AS RecordCount
FROM Frames
HAVING Frames.Package = "100";
```

Any assistance would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

> Access does not support using a parameter for `SELECT TOP`.  You must write a literal value into the text of the SQL statement.

From another answer: [Select TOP N not working in MS Access with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082041/select-top-n-not-working-in-ms-access-with-parameter/30082530#30082530)

On that note, your two queries appear to be just interchanging `HAVING` and `WHERE` clauses to get the record count. It doesn't seem to be doing anything more, thus why bother with the `TOP` clause and simply `SELECT * FROM Frames WHERE [..]`?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Good question, so my goal is to try and find how many 100's and updated only that number of records in another column to 78. Is there a better way to do it? For example, if I have 20 rows of 100 I would like to convert only 20 of 40 rows of X to 78. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @prodigerati You can look into using VBA to run and manipulate SQL strings.

Here's a good [start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626.aspx)