# SELECT TOP x in MS Access query based on form field?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an Access report whose `Record Source` references a couple of fields on a form.  It works fine.  This is it, minus a bunch fields in the `SELECT` clause for simplicity:

```sql
SELECT
    pt.PA,
    pt.SpfCode
FROM
    PtHead AS pt
    LEFT JOIN tblProblems AS p ON pt.PA = p.PantagNo
WHERE
    pt.PA = [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![PA] AND
    p.ComplaintDate >= [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![StartDate];
```

I want to upgrade this report so that it only shows the most recent records.  This works fine:

```sql
SELECT TOP 20  -- NEW PART
    pt.PA,
    pt.SpfCode
FROM
    PtHead AS pt
    LEFT JOIN tblProblems AS p ON pt.PA = p.PantagNo
WHERE
    pt.PA = [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![PA] AND
    p.ComplaintDate >= [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![StartDate]
ORDER BY p.ComplaintDate DESC;  -- NEW PART
```

However, I don't want it to be hard-coded to `TOP 20`.  I want it to be `TOP x`, based on another field on that same form.  The following fails:

```sql
SELECT TOP [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![MaxProblems]  -- FAILS HERE
    pt.PA,
    pt.SpfCode
FROM
    PtHead AS pt
    LEFT JOIN tblProblems AS p ON pt.PA = p.PantagNo
WHERE
    pt.PA = [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![PA] AND
    p.ComplaintDate >= [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![StartDate]
ORDER BY p.ComplaintDate DESC;
```

Error:

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

Can I alter the syntax to make this work?  If not, what can I do?  Do I have to overwrite the entire query text each time the report is run via VBA instead?

Comment: The TOP number cannot be dynamic in query object so you have answered your own question. Use VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Access does not support using a parameter for SELECT TOP.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30082530/77335)

Revise the *Record Source* SQL in the *After Update* event of that `[Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![MaxProblems]` control.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since the `TOP` number cannot be parameterized and hence use form fields, consider creating a running count by descending dates that you can then filter. But just be forewarned that for larger tables, this correlated subquery can pose performance challenges.

```sql
SELECT 
    pt.PA,
    pt.SpfCode
FROM
    PtHead AS pt
    LEFT JOIN tblProblems AS p ON pt.PA = p.PantagNo
WHERE
     pt.PA = [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![PA]
 AND p.ComplaintDate >= [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![StartDate]
 AND (SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM PtHead sub_pt
      LEFT JOIN tblProblems AS sub_p ON sub_pt.PA = sub_p.PantagNo
      WHERE sub_p.ComplaintDate >= p.ComplaintDate) <= [Forms]![fdlgQualityHistory]![MaxProblems];
```

Maybe one day MS Access will support window functions and join the others in RDBMS world to avoid the correlated subquery:

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pt.ComplaintDate DESC)
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around this query.  Would it return the x *most recent* records?  Or just *any* x records?  I would think the `ORDER BY` would need to go in the subquery to have an effect.  Also, I think there is a typo in this line since there are two aliases: `LEFT JOIN tblProblems sub_p AS p ON pt.PA = p.PantagNo`.  I'm not quite sure how to fix it myself.

Comment: Correct on typos and I needed an inequality `<=`. No `ORDER BY` is needed. The correlated subquery is creating an integer ranking by descending *ComplaintDate* and `WHERE` filters to all ranks until the form's control (i.e., all 1 - 20 if form control is 20).

Comment: Ah, ok I understand it now.  I'm not going to use it because the report is already slow, but it's interesting (+1).  I edited the answer to fix the remaining issues I saw: fixed table aliases and removed `ORDER BY` since Access reports ignore it and `TOP` (which had needed it) is now gone.